# Does Nautilus hook work with player created terrain?

Tags: league-of-legends

In the most recent patch they changed vayne's condemn so that it works with player created terrain. Does anyone know if this will also apply to Nautilus or if it already does? I use to play Nautilus quite a bit and I always thought it was funny that you could hook out of Jarvan Ult. Any input would be great.

Comment: They haven't specified that in the patch notes. However I guess it was always been possible. I'll test it out.

Comment: Off-topic but, @Fabián ["Irelio"](http://i.imgur.com/DQk7wpJ.jpg) is amazing! LOL!! On-topic Usually they don't change something like that

Comment: but it would make sense wouldnt it, for his hook to work on player created terrain?

Comment: @Trust Yup. Someone should point that out in a feedback forum. Michel ty! haha

Comment: I forgot to update the answer after patch 4.17. Now Nautilus collides with player-created terrain, answer updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As displayed in the [patch notes (4.17)](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-417-notes), now Nautilus' Q does collide with player created terrain.

Comment: As a matter of fact now that I think of the question title, I'll have to make another video about the other champions that can also create terrain, like Anivia, Azir (soon), etc..

Comment: Heres a red to add to your answer http://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/2fxrj8/patch_416_notes/ckdxwuk

Answer (score 3):

[**Update with 4.17**](http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-417-notes#patch-nautilus):

> NEW - NAUTICAL EQUALITY Nautilus can now drag himself to player-created terrain (e.g. Trundle's Pillar, Jarvan's Cataclysm, Anivia's Crystallize)